# What's the meaning of 忘形 and 将 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

Question as in the subject.

老虎得意得简直忘了形，完全忘了注意周围会有什么危险，屡次从芦苇丛中挑起，将自己的身体暴露在农夫的视线里.

Are commas in this sentence used to list things that the tiger forgot about? And thus does 将 introduce one of things the tiger forgot about - that he WILL (将) be seen by the farmer?

忘形 seems to mean "lose his mind" but no dictionary I looked through didn't give this meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commas are just commas.

得意忘形：dizzy with success, lost in exhilaration
将 = 把 as Ben Jackson said.

I don't know what happened before this. The tiger must have done something cool, he is very pleased with himself. There is a farmer with a weapon hiding in the reeds. Looks like the Tigerrr will be a nice fur rug soon!

老虎得意得简直忘了形，
The tiger, dizzy his with success
完全忘了注意周围会有什么危险，
completely forgot that there might be danger in his surroundings
屡次从芦苇丛中挑起，
repeated stirrings from the reed clusters
将自己的身体暴露在农夫的视线里.
put him in the farmer's line of sight

Answer (score 4):

In this case, 将 is a written form of 把. See [Using "jiang" as a formal "ba"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22jiang%22_as_a_formal_%22ba%22).

I think 形 here is just literally "appearance". The tiger forgot (overlooked) his appearance (and the effect of his appearance) and let himself be seen.

Answer (score 2):

得意忘形 is a Chinese idiom. This sentence breaks it into two pieces "得意" and "忘形".

将 is equivalent to the "make" in the "make itself visible to the farmers".

Functionalities of commas in Chinese are often different than those in English. Here they are used for separating the long sentence into small pieces so that reader won't get lost.